# Bash =~ regex and https://regex101.com/

Tags: bash, regular-expression

Using https://regex101.com/ I built a regular expression to return the first occurrence of an IP address in a string.

RegExp:

```
(?:\d{1,3}\.)+(?:\d{1,3})
```

RegExp including delimiters:

```
/(?:\d{1,3}\.)+(?:\d{1,3})/
```

With the following test string:

```
eu-west                       140.243.64.99
```

It returns a full match of:

```
140.243.64.99
```

No matter what I try with anchors etc, the following bash script will not work with the regular expression generated.

```
temp="eu-west                       140.243.64.99            "
regexp="(?:\d{1,3}\.)+(?:\d{1,3})"
if [[ $temp =~ $regexp ]]; then
  echo "found a match"
else
  echo "No IP address returned"
fi
```

Comment: That looks like a Perl regular expression to me. Bash does not support that.

Comment: The `=~` operator is discussed [here in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b) where it's written bash uses "extended regular expressions". Extended regexes are described in the [`regex(7)` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/regex.7.html) and briefly summarized [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/egrep-regular-expression-syntax.html).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`\d` is a nonstandard way for saying "any digit". I think it comes from Perl, and a lot of other languages and utilities support Perl-compatible REs (PCRE), too. (and e.g. GNU grep 2.27 in Debian stretch supports the similar `\w` for word characters even in normal mode.)

Bash doesn't support `\d`, though, so you need to explicitly use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`. Same for the non-capturing group `(?:..)`, use just `(..)` instead.

This should print `match`:

```
temp="eu-west                       140.243.64.99            "
regexp="([0-9]{1,3}\.)+([0-9]{1,3})"
[[ $temp =~ $regexp ]] && echo match
```

Comment: Does your GNU `grep` support `\d` without `-P`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, whoops, of course not. It does support `\w` and `\b`, which I've learned from Perl, so I got that confused.

Comment: it's not really fair to say `\d` or PCRE are "nonstandard".  They are quite standard, just a different standard from original regular expressions and extended regular expressions.

Comment: @DanielFarrell, the standard in this case is [what POSIX specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html), and it doesn't know about `\d`. Though you're right in that PCRE are rather standard, or in the least well-defined. The annoying issue is that GNU grep (or glibc) supports some PCRE-like atoms, at least `\w` and `\s` when interpreting ERE, and in that context they very much _are_ nonstandard. My phrasing may well come partly from that, and the misrecollection that `\d` was similarly GNU-supported.

Answer (score 5):

`(:...)` and `\d` are perl or PCRE regular expression operators (like in GNU `grep -P`).

`bash` only supports extended regular expressions as in `grep -E` except that for regexps passed literally as in `[[ text =~ regexp-here ]]` as opposed to as the result of an unquoted expansion (as in `[[ text =~ $var ]]` or `[[ test =~ $(printf '%s\n' 'regexp-here') ]]`), it's limited to the POSIX extended regular expression feature set.

So even on systems where the `grep -E '\d'` would work (GNU EREs have already imported some extensions from perl regexps like `\s` so future versions might have `\d` as well), you'd have to use:

```
regexp='\d'
[[ $text =~ $regexp ]]
```

in `bash` for it to work (`[[ $text =~ \d ]]` wouldn't).

For a shell that supports PCREs, you may want to use `zsh` instead:

```
set -o rematchpcre
[[ $text =~ '(?:\d{1,3}\.)+(?:\d{1,3})' ]]
```

ksh93 also supports its own implementation of perl-like regular expressions (not fully compatible) as part of its pattern matching. There, you'd use:

```
regexp='~(P)(?:\d{1,3}\.)+(?:\d{1,3})'
[[ $text = $regexp ]]
```

(note the `=` instead of `=~`. You'll want to use temporary variables as the it is very buggy when you don't)

Comment: Do not put quotes around regex string. `The quotes around the right-hand side of the =~ operator cause it to become a string, rather than a RegularExpression. If you want to use a long or complicated regular expression and avoid lots of backslash escaping, put it in a variable`. Source: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5B.5B_.24foo_.3D.2BAH4_.27some_RE.27_.5D.5D

Answer (score 1):

The site [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) use PCRE (look at the upper left corner) as the default, and it lacks support for "Extended" regex syntax. That is "Perl Compatible Regular Expresions", which come (as is reasonable to expect) from Perl.

PCRE is supported by some tools (like `grep -P`) under some conditions, but the bash regex support inside the `[[…]]` idiom is only for extended regex (like `grep -E`).

In Extended regex, the non-capture `(?…)` parenthesis does not exist, and the \d is also missing. You need to use simple `(…)` and `[0-9]`:

```
regexp="([0-9]{1,3}\.)+([0-9]{1,3})"
```