# Can't capture regex group?

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I have Bash script below, trying to capture last digits of 'pingnet' but can not get a match. I verified in regex101 and my regex is correct:

```
pingnet="pingcount,site=DC,cur=200 total-up=988"
regex='(\d+)$'
if [[ $pingnet =~ $regex ]]
then
    echo "YES"
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
    echo "NOT"
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

The result of running script is NOT.

Comment: `\d` doesn't work with bash's ERE, you need to use `[0-9]`

Comment: Maybe this will help:  bash ERE regular expressions do not have the `\d` as explained in [Bash =~ regex and https://regex101.com/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421460/bash-regex-and-https-regex101-com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash's regex syntax does not recognize `\d`; use `[[:digit:]]` instead:

```
pingnet="pingcount,site=DC,cur=200 total-up=988"
regex='([[:digit:]]+)$'
```