# Regex in Bash for Git Push Output

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression

Working on a simple script to backup some IDE settings and to learn bash scripting.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
NEWLINE=$'\n'
pushRegex='^([0-z]{7}[\.]{2}[0-z]{7}\s{2})(\w+)\s{1}(->)\s{1}(\w+)'
pr2='[(0-z)]{7}[(\.)]{2}[(0-z)]{7}\s{1}(\w+\s(->)\s\w+)$'
pr3='^[(0-z)]{7}(\.){2}[(0-z)]{7}(\s+\w+\s+(->)\s\w+)'
pr4='^\w+\s(\w+)(.|\w+)(\w+)(.|\w+)(\w+:\w+[/](\w+.git))\n\s+([0-z]){7}[.]{2}([0-z]){7}\s+\w+\s(->)\s\w+'

echo "Copying current settings..."
cp ${HOMEPATH}/path/to/settings.txt ./ -f

echo "Checking the stage..."
gitAdd="$(git add ./)"
gitStatus="$(git status)"

echo "${NEWLINE}${NEWLINE}Does stage have changes?"
hasChanges="Changes to be committed:"
nothingToCommit="nothing to commit"

if [[ $gitStatus == *$hasChanges* ]]; then
    echo "${NEWLINE}Changes detected${NEWLINE}Committing changes..."
    stamp="$(date --date='TZ="America/New_York" today')"
    git commit -m "Settings update: ${stamp}"

    echo "${NEWLINE}Attempting push..."
    pushAttempt="$(git push --dry-run 2>&1)"

    echo "${NEWLINE}${NEWLINE}Output of dry run attempt:${NEWLINE}"
    echo "${pushAttempt}"

    if [[ $pushAttempt == *"->"* ]]; then
        echo "we should push things"
        else
        echo "nothin to do"
    fi

    echo "${NEWLINE}Regex: ${pushRegex}"
    if [[ $pushAttempt =~ $pushRegex ]]; then
        echo "Matched regex!"
    else 
        echo "Did not match :("
    fi

    echo "${NEWLINE}Regex: ${pr2}"
    if [[ $pushAttempt =~ $pr2 ]]; then
        echo "Matched regex!"
    else 
        echo "Did not match :("
    fi

    echo "${NEWLINE}Regex: ${pr3}"
    if [[ $pushAttempt =~ $pr3 ]]; then
        echo "Matched regex!"
    else 
        echo "Did not match :("
    fi

    echo "${NEWLINE}Regex: ${pr4}"
    if [[ $pushAttempt =~ $pr4 ]]; then
        echo "Matched regex!"
    else 
        echo "Did not match :("
    fi
fi
```

I was able to get some sample text working on https://www.regextester.com and https://regexr.com, with the 4th regex with sample text like:

```
To github.company.com:username/reponame.git
   1a2b3C4..1a2b3C5  somebranchname -> maybeanotherbranchname
```

but the above code keeps printing it doesn't match.

I think I'm missing something with how the shell interprets regular expressions, but am not aware of its quirks if any.

Do regex's need a `$` at the end? I've tried some variations on `^` and combinations of the two but have yet to get things matching.

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y) and [Bash =~ regex and https://regex101.com/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421460/bash-regex-and-https-regex101-com)

Comment: Thank you, will take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are asking in particular about the regular expression to match the output of the attempted `git push` command, here a starting point to work on.

```
#!/bin/bash

pushAttempt='To github.company.com:username/reponame.git
   1a2b3C4..1a2b3C5  somebranchname -> maybeanotherbranchname'

printf "Output of dry run attempt:\n${pushAttempt}\n\n"

pr5=$'^[^\n]*\n[[:space:]]*[0-z]{7}[.]{2}[0-z]{7}.*->.*$'

printf "Regex:\n${pr5}\n\n"
if [[ $pushAttempt =~ $pr5 ]]; then
    echo "Matched regex!"
else 
    echo "Did not match :("
fi
```

One of the main point in your failing regular expression is that you are trying to match the string from the beginning with `^`, but your regex seems to try to match only the second line of `pushAttempt`. I ignored the first line matching anything but a newline zero or more times followed by a newline. Of course, other approaches are possible and it depends from what can be contained in the string you are trying to match. Another point is that you should use [POSIX character classes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions#Character_classes), e.g. `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s`.

About the last `.*->.*$` part of the regex, you can make it stricter to your tastes and needs, but starting a regex with `^` and ending it with `$` you require a full match of the string.

#### Bonus track

You could use `git status --untracked-files=no --porcelain` in order to simplify your logic to understand if there are changes to be committed. In general `git` offers options to make commands output more "script friendly" and it is worth checking out the documentation before parsing the output; [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) about `git status`.

Comment: Thank you, especially for taking the time to explain!